# SQL Server : check for duplicate foreign key to each user (given a synthetic primary key)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where the primary key is just a synthetic key to keep track of each user's tracked orders. A user cannot have duplicate orders, but can have as many different orders to track as they want. My problem is that I want to increase performance by moving my current solution (checking for duplicates in the query) to changing it into a CHECK constraint or something similar.

Table

```
| TrackingId | OrderId | UserId |
+------------+---------+--------+
| 1          | 37      | 144    |
| 2          | 41      | 144    |
| 3          | 37      | 144    | -- DUPLICATE
| 4          | 41      | 26     | -- But this is fine
```

Is it possible to create a CHECK constraint to prevent inserting data into the table in this case?

To clarify, instead of having to add the process of checking for an already existing record in my SQL code for my application, can I add code into the database schema to check so it will just throw an error if it fails the CHECK constraint?

e.g.

```
DECLARE @userId INT
DECLARE @orderId INT

--(the database handles the check for you)
INSERT INTO Tracking
...
```

instead of:

```
DECLARE @userId INT
DECLARE @orderId INT

IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Tracking
    WHERE UserId = @userId AND OrderId = @orderId
    GROUP BY UserId, OrderId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0) > 0

    -- Check failed (User already has a record for that particular OrderId, can't add it again)
    THROW 51000, 'Cannot insert duplicate order for user.', 1;

ELSE
(
    INSERT INTO Tracking
    ...
)
```

Comment: And why not add a Unique Constraint on the 2 columns ?

Comment: A check constraint is generally limited to values within a given row - so the idea of using it to check across multiple rows contradicts that purpose. Short answer is no - longer answer is yes (with complications). Better answer is a unique constraint as already suggested. BTW - the idea of moving your logic to "improve performance" does not make sense. Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want a *unique* constraint, not a *check* constraint:

```
alter table tracking 
    add constraint unq_tracking_userid_orderid unique (userid, orderid);
```

Comment: If I create this unique constraint, will I be able to add more of that OrderId to the table under a different UserId?

Comment: @MattD . . . You could add one row of the OrderId to each UserId.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the concept of unique constraints/indices here:
[SQL Server Create Unique Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-unique-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)
In your case the code should be:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_tracking_userid_orderid ON tracking (userid, orderid);
```